# Upgradable Proxy to ERC1155

Tags: solidity, python, brownie, erc-1155, proxy-contracts

I want to upgrade my ERC1155 game from Game.sol to GameV2.sol using Openzeppelin's contracts ProxyAdmin and TransparentUpgradeableProxy. I have implemented ERC1155PresetMinterPauser to Game/GameV2 contracts in order to be able set roles, change game parameters etc. afterwards.

During testing the functionality of the proxy by using function `setBurnToGainParameters` from GameV2.sol via proxy (details related to all steps made can be seen in deploy_proxy.py below), I get:

```
>>> proxy_nft_game_V2.setBurnToGainParameters(0, 1, {"from": owner})
Transaction sent: 0x448645520a6f3db29beb700a17cad884cdcb3e771797af0653f9cd81b4e7189e
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 5
  Transaction confirmed (ERC1155PresetMinterPauser: must have admin role to change variables)   Block: 6   Gas used: 25756 (0.21%)
```

So, I tried to check, if owner adress (me) has a admin role, i.e. `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`:

```
>>> nft_game_V2.hasRole(ADMIN_ROLE, owner)
True
>>> proxy_nft_game_V2.hasRole(ADMIN_ROLE, owner)
False
```

Based on https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies#proxy-forwarding

> A very important thing to note is that the code makes use of the EVM’s delegatecall opcode which executes the callee’s code in the context of the caller’s state. That is, the logic contract controls the proxy’s state and the logic contract’s state is meaningless. Thus, the proxy doesn’t only forward transactions to and from the logic contract, but also represents the pair’s state. The state is in the proxy and the logic is in the particular implementation that the proxy points to.

I guess that the admin and any other variables defined in the GameV2 are actually not stored in the proxy contract. Question is what is the proper way to set them in the proxy and be able to call all functions required roles (admin's, minter, etc.)?

Could anyone help me, please?

To reproduced, please see the following lines of code:

**deploy_proxy.py**

```py
from scripts.helpers import deploy_proxy, upgrade
from brownie import Game, GameV2, Contract, exceptions, config, network, accounts
from web3 import Web3


def deploy_game_and_proxy():
    owner = accounts[0]

    # deploy game V1
    nft_game = Game.deploy(
        {"from": owner},
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("publish", False),
        )

    # deploy proxy
    proxy_admin, proxy_nft_game, proxy = deploy_proxy(owner, nft_game, "Game")

    # deploy game V2
    nft_game_V2 = GameV2.deploy(
        {"from": owner},
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("publish", False),
        )

    # upgrade
    upgrade_nft_game = upgrade(
        owner,
        proxy,
        nft_game_V2.address,
        proxy_admin_contract = proxy_admin,
        initializer=None,
    )
    upgrade_nft_game.wait(1)

    # get proxy of game B2
    proxy_nft_game_V2 = Contract.from_abi(
        "GameV2", proxy.address, GameV2.abi,
    )

    # set the new parameters
    proxy_nft_game_V2.setBurnToGainParameters(0, 1, {"from": owner})


def main():
    deploy_game_and_proxy()
```

**helpers.py**

```py
from brownie import (
    network, config, Contract,
    TransparentUpgradeableProxy, ProxyAdmin,
)
import eth_utils


NON_FORKED_LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = ["hardhat", "development", "ganache"]
LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = NON_FORKED_LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS + [
    "mainnet-fork",
]


def encode_function_data(initializer=None, *args):
    """
    Encodes the function call so we can work with an initializer.

    Args:
        initializer ([brownie.network.contract.ContractTx], optional):
        The initializer function we want to call. Example: 'box.store'.
        Defaults to None.

        args (Any, optional):
        The arguments to pass to the initializer function.

    Returns:
        [bytes]: Return the encoded bytes.
    """
    if len(args) == 0 or not initializer:
        return eth_utils.to_bytes(hexstr="0x") # to return at least some bytes;
    return initializer.encode_input(*args)


def upgrade(
    account,
    proxy,
    new_implementation_address,
    proxy_admin_contract=None,
    initializer=None,
    *args
    ):
    """
    Update our proxy contract:

    Args:
        account (string, address): the caller account private key
        proxy (string, contract): the proxy contract to be updated
        new_implementation_address (string, address): the address of implementation contract (the new one)
        proxy_admin_contract (string, contract, optional): if admin contract exists
        initializer (string, optional): if initializer exists (to be encoded)
        *args (Any, optional): if *args exists (parameter to be encoded with initializer)
    """
    transaction = None
    if proxy_admin_contract:
        if initializer:
            # encode initiliazer in bytes
            encoded_function_call = encode_function_data(initializer, *args)
            # upgrade the proxy admin contract with encoded initializer
            transaction = proxy_admin_contract.upgradeAndCall(
                proxy.address,
                new_implementation_address,
                encoded_function_call,
                {"from": account},
            )
        else:
            # upgrade the proxy admin contract WITHOUT encoded initializer
            transaction = proxy_admin_contract.upgrade(
                proxy.address,
                new_implementation_address,
                {"from": account},
            )
    else:
    # if proxy admin does not exists
        if initializer:
            # encode initiliazer in bytes
            encoded_function_call = encode_function_data(initializer, *args)
            transaction = proxy.upgradeToAndCall(
                new_implementation_address,
                encoded_function_call,
                {"from": account},
            )
        else:
            transaction == proxy.upgradeTo(
                new_implementation_address,
                {"from": account},
            )
    return transaction


def deploy_proxy(account, contract_deployed, contract_name="contract", initilizer=None, *args):
    # 1.create proxy admin
    proxy_admin = ProxyAdmin.deploy(
        {"from": account},
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("publish", False)
        )
    # 2.encode initiazer
    if initilizer:
        encoded_initiliazer = encode_function_data(initilizer, *args)
    else:
        encoded_initiliazer = encode_function_data()
    # 3.create proxy
    proxy = TransparentUpgradeableProxy.deploy(
        contract_deployed.address,
        proxy_admin.address,
        encoded_initiliazer,
        {"from": account, "gas_limit": 1000000},
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("publish", False)
    )
    # 4. create proxy contract
    proxy_contract = Contract.from_abi(
        contract_name, proxy.address, contract_deployed.abi
    )
    return proxy_admin, proxy_contract, proxy
```

**Game.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/presets/ERC1155PresetMinterPauser.sol";

contract Game is ERC1155PresetMinterPauser, Ownable {

    uint256 public constant APPLE = 0;
    uint256 public constant PEAR = 1;
    uint256 public constant CHERRY = 2;

    uint256[] public mintedTotal = [0, 0, 0];
    uint256 public mintedPublicly;
    uint256 public maxAvailableForPublicMint = 1000;
    uint256[] public ratesForPublicMint = [0.01 ether, 0.01 ether, 0.01 ether];

    // Mapping from token ID to Users's balances
    mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) private Users;

    // variable related to burning item in order to mint another item
    uint256 public fruitToBurn = PEAR;
    uint256 public fruitToMint = CHERRY;

    constructor() ERC1155PresetMinterPauser("https://address.io/{id}.json")
    {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());
    }

    function mint(address user, uint256 id, uint256 amount) public {
        require(hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, _msgSender()), "ERC1155PresetMinterPauser: must have minter role to mint");
        require(0 <= id && id <= mintedTotal.length, "Fruit does not exists!");
        mintedTotal[id] = mintedTotal[id].add(amount);
        Users[id][user] = Users[id][user].add(amount);
        _mint(user, id, amount, "");
    }

    // withdraw ETH sent to the contract (during public Mint for instance)
    function withdraw() public {
        require(hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender()), "ERC1155PresetMinterPauser: must have minter role to mint");
        require(address(this).balance > 0, "Balance is zero, cannot withdraw");
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    // burn allowed fruit in order to try luck in getting different fruit
    function burnToGainFruit(uint256 id, uint256 amount) public {
        require(0 <= id && id <= mintedTotal.length, "Fruit does not exists!");
        require(id == fruitToBurn, "This fruit cannot be burnt!");
        address user = msg.sender;
        for (uint i=1; i <= amount; i++) {
            require(Users[id][user] > 0, "There is nothing to burn");
            Users[id][user] = Users[id][user].sub(1);
            _burn(user, id, 1);
        }
    }

}
```

**GameV2.sol** (= Game.sol extended by `setBurnToGainParameters` function)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/presets/ERC1155PresetMinterPauser.sol";

contract GameV2 is ERC1155PresetMinterPauser, Ownable {

    uint256 public constant APPLE = 0;
    uint256 public constant PEAR = 1;
    uint256 public constant CHERRY = 2;

    uint256[] public mintedTotal = [0, 0, 0];
    uint256 public mintedPublicly;
    uint256 public maxAvailableForPublicMint = 1000;
    uint256[] public ratesForPublicMint = [0.01 ether, 0.01 ether, 0.01 ether];

    // Mapping from token ID to Users's balances

    mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) private Users;
    // variable related to burning item in order to mint another item
    uint256 public fruitToBurn = PEAR;
    uint256 public fruitToMint = CHERRY;

    constructor() ERC1155PresetMinterPauser("https://address.io/{id}.json")
    {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());
    }

    function mint(address user, uint256 id, uint256 amount) public {
        require(hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, _msgSender()), "ERC1155PresetMinterPauser: must have minter role to mint");
        require(0 <= id && id <= mintedTotal.length, "Fruit does not exists!");
        mintedTotal[id] = mintedTotal[id].add(amount);
        Users[id][user] = Users[id][user].add(amount);
        _mint(user, id, amount, "");
    }

    // withdraw ETH sent to the contract (during public Mint for instance)
    function withdraw() public {
        require(hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender()), "ERC1155PresetMinterPauser: must have minter role to mint");
        require(address(this).balance > 0, "Balance is zero, cannot withdraw");
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    // burn allowed fruit in order to try luck in getting different fruit
    function burnToGainFruit(uint256 id, uint256 amount) public {
        require(0 <= id && id <= mintedTotal.length, "Fruit does not exists!");
        require(id == fruitToBurn, "This fruit cannot be burnt!");
        address user = msg.sender;
        for (uint i=1; i <= amount; i++) {
            require(Users[id][user] > 0, "There is nothing to burn");
            Users[id][user] = Users[id][user].sub(1);
            _burn(user, id, 1);
        }
    }

    function setBurnToGainParameters(uint256 _fruitToBurn, uint256 _fruitToMint)
    external returns (bool) {
        require(hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender()), "ERC1155PresetMinterPauser: must have admin role to change variables");
        require(0 <= _fruitToBurn && _fruitToBurn < mintedTotal.length, "Fruit to burn does not exists!");
        require(0 <= _fruitToMint && _fruitToMint < mintedTotal.length, "Fruit to mint does not exists!");
        fruitToBurn = _fruitToBurn;
        fruitToMint = _fruitToMint;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for making this question. Right now, it's in "please debug my code mode". This platform strives to serve minimalistic questions that others might have. Can you minimize your question so others could help you?

Comment: @PatrickCollins thank you for you feedback. To clarify, it was not my intension to have others to debug my code, sorry for that. I tried to be more specific and edited the question. Hope is okay, happy to further improve.